# Rabbitmq one queue multiple consumers

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I've multiple consumers which are polling on the same queue, and checking the queue every X seconds, basically after X seconds it could be that at least two consumers can launch `basic.get` at the very same time.

Question are:
1.If at least two consumers at the same time can get the same message?

2.According to what I understood only `basic_ack` will delete a mesage from the queue, so suppose we have the following scenario:

`Consumer1` takes msg with basic.get and before it reaches `basic_ack` line , `Consumer2` is getting this message also (`basic.get`), now `Consumer1` reaches the `basic.ack`, and only now `Consumer2` reaches its own `basic.ack`.
 What will happen When Consumer2 will reach its `basic.ack`?
Will the message be processes by Consumer2 as well, because actions are not atomic?

My code logic of consumer using python pika is as follows:

`while true:
     m_frame =None
     while(m_frame is None):

        self.connection.sleep(10)
        m_frame,h_frame,body = self.channel.basic_get('test_queue')
     self.channel.basic_ack(m_frame.delivery_tag)
     [Doing some long logic - couple of minutes]`

**Please note that I don't use basic.consume**

So I don't know if round robin fetching is included for such usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.If at least two consumers at the same time can get the same message?

no - a single message will only be delivered to a single consumer.

Because of that, your scenario #2 doesn't come into play at all.

You'll never have 2 consumers working on the same message, unless you `nack` the message back to the queue but continue processing it anyways.